# How to get sum of the same Unit's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a college's departments and their units and sub-units.

```
OrganizationID  ParentUnit  Unit    ChildUnit   UnitName
            10           1     0            0   Education
            12           1     1            0   Sports
            24           1     2            0   Mathmatics
            28           1     3            0   Science
            35           1     3            1   Physics
            51           1     4            0   Arts
            66           1     4            1   Music
            69           1     4            2   Painting
            84           8     0            0   Business & Administration
            88           8     1            0   Administration
            96           8     1            1   Public Administration 
           107           8     1            2   Local Managements
           110           8     2            0   Finance
           119           8     2            1   Accounting
           124           8     2            2   Marketing
```

I have another table which contains the student information of that college.

```
StudentID  OrganizationID
        1              12
        2              12
        3              24
        5              28
        6              35
        8              51
        9              66
       31              69
       34              96
       45              88
       57              96
       66             107
       69             110
       72              69
       74             124
```

I want to get student counts for each unit. If a studutent's Organization is a  `ChildUnit` it should be added to current `Unit`. If ChildUnit is greater than`0` corresponding student count should be added to same `Unit` For example `Physics` is a child of `Science`. Then `Science` student count should return 2.

My target data table should look like as the following

```
ParentUnit                    UnitName    StudentCount
------------------------------------------------------
Education                     Sports                 2
Education                     Mathmatics             1
Education                     Science                2
Education                     Arts                   4
Business & Administration     Administration         4
Business & Administration     Finance                2
```

I have done it in programmatic way. There are many for and if loops. Then I started to think whether it could be done with a smarter sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look so difficult. You are looking for the student count per ParentUnit + Unit. Then the name for such a group is the record where the level (the ChildUnit) is zero. You get that record with a CASE construct, then use MIN or MAX, because you need an aggregate function here (there should be exactly one record per group anyhow, so MIN = MAX).

```
select 
  min(case when o.childunit = 0 then o.unitname end) as unitname,
  count(*) as studentcount
from organization o
inner join student s on s.organizationid = o.organizationid
group by o.parentunit, o.unit;
```

To include the parent unit name:

```
select 
  (
    select unitname 
    from organization po 
    where po.parentunit = o.parentunit
    and po.unit =0
    and po.childunit = 0
  ) as parentunitname,
  min(case when o.childunit = 0 then o.unitname end) as unitname,
  count(*) as studentcount
from organization o
inner join student s on s.organizationid = o.organizationid
group by o.parentunit, o.unit;
```

Or:

```
select 
  min(po.unitname) as parentunitname,
  min(case when o.childunit = 0 then o.unitname end) as unitname,
  count(*) as studentcount
from organization o
inner join student s on s.organizationid = o.organizationid
inner join 
(
  select parentunit, unitname
  from organization 
  where unit = 0 and childunit = 0
) po on po.parentunit = o.parentunit
group by o.parentunit, o.unit;
```

Comment: may I request getting a third column as ParentUnit's name? `ParentUnit, Unit, StudentCount`

Comment: Is there a ParentUnits table that holds the name for each ParentUnit? Then: `select (select name from parentunits p where p.parentunit = o.parentunit) as parentunit, min(case ...` Or join that table and either use MIN or MAX on the name or have name in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No, all the units in the same table. ParentUnit, Unit and ChildUnit columns identify which unit is under which one.

Comment: Ah, I guess I see now. The ParentUnit Name is the one with Unit = 0 and ChildUnit = 0, yes? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said. I have tried `min(case when o.childunit = 0 then o.unitname end) as unitname, count(*) as studentcount, min(case when o.unit = 0 then o.unitname end) as parentunitname ...` but parentunitname comes null for all rows.

Comment: As we are grouping by parentunit/unit, e.g. 1/3 for Science, we don't see the 1/0 record for Education. It is simply not within the 1/3 group of records. So we must query that record separately.

Comment: sorry. did not work. It says "Column `organization.unitname` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause."

Comment: Oh, well. I consider this a weakness in the dbms, as the sub-select depends on a group column only (o.parentunit) and not on any non-aggregated column such as o.childunit. However, you can circumvent this by adding MIN or MAX: `select min((select unitname ...)) ...`. Or use the alternative query I posted.